# Hibernate many-to-many relation returns empty collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am adding a many-to-many relationship between two entities in my Spring Boot application. I have the following mappings:

Business.java:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "business_vendor",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "business_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id"))
@JSON(include = false)
protected List<Vendor> vendors;
```

Vendor.java

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vendors")
@JSON(include = false)
protected List<Business> businesses;
```

I am able to add a vendor to a business then save it to the database. However, when (in a new request) I load a business then call `business.getVendors()`, I get an empty List. I can see from the application logs that Hibernate is selecting from the linking table, and if I run that Hibernate-generated query against the database manually, I see one row as I expect. I have tried switching the FetchMode to eager and have tried removing `CascadeType.ALL`, neither of which has helped.

This application is on Hibernate 4.3.11 (cannot upgrade at this time for "reasons").

Edit: Here is a minimal example:

```
public List<Vendor> getVendorsForBusiness(UUID businessId) {
    Business business = businessRepository.findOne(businessId.toString());
    return business.getVendors();
}
```

I expect this to return a List with 1 Vendor, but I get an empty List, even though there is a row in the linking table in the database.

Edit 2: Here is the relevant portion of the persist method I am using, which does successfully create a row in the business_vendor table:

```
public void addVendorToBusiness(UUID businessId, UUID vendorId) {
    Vendor vendor = vendorRepository.findOne(vendorId.toString());
    Business business = businessRepository.findOne(businessId.toString());
    business.getVendors().add(vendor);
    vendor.getBusinesses().add(business); // This line doesn't make a difference
    businessRepository.save(business);
}
```

Comment: Build a minimal example with the persist method. The mapping looks good.

Comment: I am in agreement with @jklee.  I more complete example would help others respond to your question.

Comment: How you save the entities? The mapping works into my project.

Comment: Strange. I think the problem is deeper.

Comment: I wonder if there is something odd going on with the lazy loading proxy. If I walk through the code in a debugger, I can see that the query to select the vendors is getting run at the start of the `getVendors` method, but then the `vendors` List that gets returned by the getter still has a size of 0. Unfortunately IntelliJ's debugger won't let me step inside the function that lazy loads the data however, so I can't see exactly what is going on at a lower level.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "business_vendor",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "business_id"**, referencedColumnName = "enter business Id name"**),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id", **referencedColumnName = "enter vendor Id name"** ))
@JSON(include = false)
protected List<Vendor> vendors;

**OR** 

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "business_vendor",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(**name = "tablename_idname"**),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(**name = "tablename_idname"**))
@JSON(include = false)
protected List<Vendor> vendors;
```

Comment: The code might answer the question but the OP won't learn why this is working now. So please explain why your code snippet answers the question.

Comment: referencedColumnName when specified will help to reference the Table while fetching data, but if referencedColumnName is NOT specified, then Hibernate tries to generate the referencedColumnName from the JoinColumn name, if it is unable to fetch Table primary key then No data will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the bidirectional strategy. Something like this:

Business.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSINESS")
public class Business implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "business_vendor",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "business_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id"))
//@JSON(include = false)
    private List<Vendor> vendors;

    public Business() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Vendor> getVendors() {
        return vendors;
    }

    public void setVendors(List<Vendor> vendors) {
        this.vendors = vendors;
    }
}
```

Vendor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENDOR")
public class Vendor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vendors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//    @JSON(include = false)
    private List<Business> businesses;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Business> getBusinesses() {
        return businesses;
    }

    public void setBusinesses(List<Business> businesses) {
        this.businesses = businesses;
    }

    public Vendor() {
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    private Session session;
    private Transaction transaction;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.save();
        List<Vendor> vList = main.getVendorFromBusinessId(2L);
        main.displayVendors(vList);

        SESSION_FACTORY.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void save() {

        this.session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
        this.transaction = null;
        try {

            this.transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();
            Business b1 = new Business();
            Business b2 = new Business();
            Business b3 = new Business();

            Vendor v1 = new Vendor();
            Vendor v2 = new Vendor();

            List<Business> bList = new ArrayList<>();
            bList.add(b1);
            bList.add(b2);
            bList.add(b3);

            List<Vendor> vList = new ArrayList<>();
            vList.add(v1);
            vList.add(v2);

            b1.setVendors(vList);
            b2.setVendors(vList);
            b3.setVendors(vList);

            v1.setBusinesses(bList);
            v2.setBusinesses(bList);

            this.session.save(b1);
            this.session.save(b2);
            this.session.save(b3);

            this.transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (this.transaction == null) {

                this.transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {

            this.session.close();
        }
    }

    private List<Vendor> getVendorFromBusinessId(Long businessId) {

        List<Vendor> vList = null;
        this.session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
        this.transaction = null;

        try {

            this.transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();
            Business business = (Business) this.session.get(Business.class, businessId);
            vList = business.getVendors();
            this.transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (this.transaction == null) {

                this.transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {

            this.session.close();
        }

        return vList;
    }

    private void displayVendors(List<Vendor> vList) {

        if (vList != null) {

            System.out.print("Vendor List IDs: ");
            vList.forEach((vendor) -> {
                System.out.print(vendor.getId() + " ");
            });

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

My output: 
[My Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeE7H.png)

Comment: I don't have a problem saving the relation, it's getting that I'm having a problem with. And I already tried adding `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: Well, did you tried bidirectional strategy ? After using bidirectional mapping does getVendors() returns empty ?

Comment: I have tried with the bidirectional strategy and am still getting an empty list from getVendors() after persisting.

Comment: Dear brother, may be you are missing the point again and again.  Here I'm sharing all the code segment already done and it's working.

Comment: One more thing, when you create a Business object then it's vendor list must be null because it's not initialized. So when you are calling `business.getVendors().add(vendor);` it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Hibernate will always return an empty list if there are no entries, it will never return null on a OneToMany or ManyToMany. And you're still looking in the wrong place, you're thinking that the problem is in the persisting, but it's in the fetching.

Comment: Actually the problem is your question. You have just provided `businessRepository.findOne(businessId);`. What does the businessRepository method do ? Did you described that? I thought it's providing a Business object. Whatever, I know what hibernate returns in which situation. By the way, it working in my system. You can see the output I have provided with the answer. Whatever I think you want to update an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

In the database, we use UUIDs for primary keys. However, the people who built this application decided that instead of using a Java `UUID` type, they should use `String`s for the UUIDs. So, sometimes the application would send a lowercase UUID to the database, and sometimes it would send an uppercase UUID. The database doesn't care, because UUIDs in SQL Server are case-insensitive, but Java `Strings` are case-sensitive, so Hibernate doesn't recognize that the `Business` with the lowercase UUID is the same as the `Business` with the uppercase UUID. So I had to `.toString().toUpperCase()` all of the IDs before sending them to the database to make sure they're the same.

Of course, Java `UUID`s are case-insensitive, so this whole problem could have been avoided if the people who built this software just used those instead of `String`s.