# Many-To-Many Spring JPA relationship returns no data from get()

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am adding a many-to-many relationship between two entities in my Spring Boot application using JPA. I have the following mappings:
Task class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "task_tags_dim",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags;
```

Tag class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Task> tasks;
```

The end goal is to have a task can be associated with multiple tags, and a single tag can be associated with multiple tasks. However, it seems that no matter how many times I try to add a tag to my task set, the task set does not 'save' the tags that were previously added so `currentTask.getTags()` returns no results. I've seen similar posts like this one but it hasn't exactly been helpful for my use case: [Hibernate many-to-many relation returns empty collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025076/hibernate-many-to-many-relation-returns-empty-collection)

Here is my TagService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TagService {
    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    //create() will create a tag and link it to a specific task
    public Tag create(Tag tag, Long task_id) {
        try {
            Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(task_id);
            if (optionalTask.isPresent()) {
                Task currentTask = optionalTask.get();
                Tag newTag = new Tag(tag.getName(), tag.getColor());


                //currentTask.getTags().add(newTag);
                //taskRepository.save(currentTask);

                System.out.println(currentTask.getTags().size()); //always returns 0

                Set<Tag> tags = currentTask.getTags();
                tags.add(tag);
                currentTask.setTags(tags);
                taskRepository.save(currentTask);


                return newTag;
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag '" + tag.getName() + "' already exists.");
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Task not found");
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with how I am using Cascade.type in my Task class?

After obtaining the task object from taskRepository.findById() I tried to retrieve those task's tags using getTags() but did not return any results. I also attempted to change the Fetch type to EAGER but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your many-to-many relationship is bidirectional. When you are adding a new joining entry you must add it to the both sides (both entities). Implement a helper method in the Post entity like this:

```java
public void addTag(Tag tag) {
    tags.add(tag);
    tag.getTasks().add(this);
}
```

In the service class you will call this method like this:

```java
    currentTask.addTag(newTag);
    taskRepository.save(currentTask);
```

Similar to this you should implement a method for removing the joining entry:

```java
public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
    tags.remove(tag);
    tag.getTasks().remove(this);
}
```

This way you will have the implementation in one place and the relationship will be synchronized correctly.

Based on: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

[Edit by @Mario Barragan after solving]:

I also had to override my hashCode() and equals() within the Task class, and add a @JsonIgnore header above my @ManyToMany.